# Reading modbus registers

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I have python script which reads registers from energy meter and saves values to database.

Script was working fine until today when i tried to run it and i got error:

```
AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'
```

I can ping device normally...

This is my code (half of it) - even simple print of value doesn't work anymore

```py
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

IP = "192.168.X.X"
client = ModbusTcpClient(IP)

reg = client.read_holding_registers(23322, 2)
calc = round((reg.registers[0] * pow(2, 16) + reg.registers[1]) * 0.01 / 1000, 2)

print(calc)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Just a thought: have you tried turning your meter off and on again? If that's not fixing your issue I would try to scan port 502 (or the one where the Modbus server is supposed to be listening) or check with the documentation the default port.

Answer (score 1):

The return value from `read_holding_registers`, i.e. the `reg` variable in your code, contains an instance of `ReadHoldingRegistersResponse` only if the request resulted in a valid response. In case of an invalid response, it will contain an instance of `ExceptionResponse`. So the right way for you would be something on these lines:

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.pdu import ExceptionResponse
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException

IP = "192.168.X.X"
client = ModbusTcpClient(IP)

reg = client.read_holding_registers(23322, 2)
if reg is not None and not isinstance(reg, ExceptionResponse) and not isinstance(reg, ModbusIOException):
    calc = round((reg.registers[0] * pow(2, 16) + reg.registers[1]) * 0.01 / 1000, 2)
    print(calc)
else:
    print('Modbus request failed')
```

I would also recommend you to use exception handling because sometimes pymodbus calls will raise an exception instead of failing silently with `None` return value.

Comment: Or call `reg.IsError()` (which should return true if there was an error).

Answer (score 0):

Your device is obviously returning an exception instead of the values, have a look at the type of the exception (by looking into your `reg` variable) to get a clue on how to fix it